# How can I troubleshoot mobile broadband in Debian Jessie?

Tags: debian, 3g, mobile

I have never used mobile broadband in Linux before, so I am not sure where I am going.

First some info:

The SIM works for data in my Android phone.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 017: ID 0bdb:1911 Ericsson Business Mobile Networks BV <-- THIS
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 04f2:b221 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd integrated camera
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0a5c:217f Broadcom Corp. BCM2045B (BDC-2.1)
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 147e:2016 Upek Biometric Touchchip/Touchstrip Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

and

```
$ dmesg
[15101.672779] usb 4-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 16 using ehci-pci
[15101.764082] usb 4-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bdb, idProduct=1912
[15101.764090] usb 4-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
[15101.764095] usb 4-1.4: Product: 㕆㈵朱w
[15101.764099] usb 4-1.4: SerialNumber: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[15101.835070] usbhid 4-1.4:1.0: can't add hid device: -71
[15101.835094] usbhid: probe of 4-1.4:1.0 failed with error -71
[15101.902324] usb 4-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 16
[15101.946751] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: irq 51 for MSI/MSI-X
[15102.050449] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: irq 51 for MSI/MSI-X
[15102.051087] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[15102.052383] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[15102.052660] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[15102.171033] EXT4-fs (sda2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[15102.320920] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[15102.321211] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[15102.704240] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Down
[15102.870575] usb 4-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 17 using ehci-pci
[15102.874573] [drm] Enabling RC6 states: RC6 on, RC6p off, RC6pp off
[15102.970122] usb 4-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bdb, idProduct=1911
[15102.970134] usb 4-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[15102.970139] usb 4-1.4: Product: F5521gw
[15102.970143] usb 4-1.4: Manufacturer: Lenovo
[15102.970147] usb 4-1.4: SerialNumber: XXXXXXXXXXXXX
[15103.003736] cdc_acm 4-1.4:1.1: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[15103.005284] cdc_acm 4-1.4:1.3: ttyACM1: USB ACM device
[15103.007211] cdc_wdm 4-1.4:1.5: cdc-wdm0: USB WDM device
[15103.025740] cdc_ncm 4-1.4:1.6: MAC-Address: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[15103.026234] cdc_ncm 4-1.4:1.6 wwan0: register 'cdc_ncm' at usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.4, Mobile Broadband Network Device, XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[15103.027141] cdc_wdm 4-1.4:1.8: cdc-wdm1: USB WDM device
[15103.027609] cdc_acm 4-1.4:1.9: ttyACM2: USB ACM device
[15103.196405] cdc_wdm 4-1.4:1.8: wdm_int_callback - 0 bytes
[15103.197402] cdc_wdm 4-1.4:1.5: wdm_int_callback - 0 bytes
[15103.258844] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wwan0: link is not ready
[15103.262428] cdc_ncm 4-1.4:1.6 wwan0: network connection: disconnected
[15103.270437] cdc_ncm 4-1.4:1.6 wwan0: network connection: disconnected
[15106.350246] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: DK
[15106.357956] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: DK
[15106.357963] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: ETSI
[15106.357966] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[15106.357970] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[15106.357975] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[15106.357979] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[15106.357982] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2700 mBm), (0 s)
[15106.357985] cfg80211:   (57000000 KHz - 66000000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)
[15106.438531] wlan0: Limiting TX power to 27 (30 - 3) dBm as advertised by XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[15107.871958] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG_.VID_._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20140424/nsarguments-95)
[15107.873269] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG_.VID_._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20140424/nsarguments-95)
[15108.713364] thinkpad_acpi: EC reports that Thermal Table has changed
[16214.212563] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG_.VID_._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20140424/nsarguments-95)
[16214.213750] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG_.VID_._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20140424/nsarguments-95)
[16215.053428] thinkpad_acpi: EC reports that Thermal Table has changed
```

and

```
$ ifconfig wwan
wwan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:80:37:ec:02:00  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Sometimes I see this pop-up:

[image: PIN prompt]

If I fill in the PIN it disappears. When I suspend and resume the laptop, I need to unlock the Gnome keystore.

The `nm-connection-editor` shows:
[image]

However, the Gnome3 network menu does not show it, even though I created it through this:

[image]

Clicking on 'connect' does not do anything.

How can I make this connect?

**Update but still not solved**

After running:

```
sudo systemctl enable ModemManager.service
sudo systemctl start ModemManager.service (typed PIN in popup after this)
sudo systemctl status -l ModemManager.service 
● ModemManager.service - Modem Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ModemManager.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2016-09-21 18:45:48 CEST; 17h ago
 Main PID: 1830 (ModemManager)
   CGroup: /system.slice/ModemManager.service
           └─1830 /usr/sbin/ModemManager

Sep 22 12:11:49  ModemManager[1830]: <warn>  Couldn't load unlock retries: 'Unknown error'
Sep 22 12:11:49  ModemManager[1830]: <info>  Modem: state changed (unknown -> locked)
Sep 22 12:11:49  ModemManager[1830]: <warn>  couldn't load IMSI: 'SIM PIN required'
Sep 22 12:11:49  ModemManager[1830]: <warn>  couldn't load Operator identifier: 'Cannot load Operator ID without IMSI'
Sep 22 12:11:49  ModemManager[1830]: <warn>  couldn't load Operator name: 'Could not parse the CRSM response'
Sep 22 12:11:49  ModemManager[1830]: <warn>  couldn't load list of Own Numbers: 'SIM PIN required'
Sep 22 12:28:23  ModemManager[1830]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/8: state changed (locked -> initializing)
Sep 22 12:28:24  ModemManager[1830]: <warn>  couldn't load Supported Modes: 'Couldn't retrieve supported modes'
Sep 22 12:28:25  ModemManager[1830]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/8: state changed (initializing -> disabled)
Sep 22 12:29:52  systemd[1]: Started Modem Manager.
```

Comment: Use your smartphone to unlock and disable the pin code, try to connect and update your question.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it was simply disabled under `gnome-control-center power`.

Toggling this switch made me able to press `connect` in Gnome3 or

```
sudo nmcli con up <connection name>
```

A little UI feedback would have been helpful.